# boto3 DynamoDB - Query operation: ExpressionAttributeNames contains invalid key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have the following source code to filter items from a DynamoDB.

```
    ...
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    db = session.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region, endpoint_url=endpoint)
    self.table_obj = db.Table(table_name)

    filter_expression = ':status_name <> :status_val'
    attr_names = {'status_name': 'status'}
    attr_values = {'status_val': 'UPDATED'} 

    response = table.query(FilterExpression=filter_expression,
                           ExpressionAttributeNames=attr_names,
                           ExpressionAttributeValues=attr_values)
```

However, I getting the following error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: ExpressionAttributeNames contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: "status_name"
```

I can't see anything wrong with the above code, am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Expression Attribute Name documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html)

> An expression attribute name is a placeholder that you use in an
>   Amazon DynamoDB expression as an alternative to an actual attribute
>   name. An expression attribute name must begin with a pound sign (#),
>   and be followed by one or more alphanumeric characters.

I think you are missing the pound(#) in from of your placeholder attribute names.

Try to change this

```
attr_names = {'status_name': 'status'}
```

to

```
attr_names = {'#status_name': 'status'}
```